# Got an error when I retrieve second item from Firebaase

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It is my first android app and I am so excited but I got the error in my last function. It is okay to retrieve 1st data but I got an error `"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size 1 at java.util.ArrrayList.get()"` when I retrieve second data from firebase database

Here is my program

```
//start here
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Wishlist");

myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        List<String> wishlist_item = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String data = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            wishlist_item.add(data);
        }


        //list 1
        L1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String a = wishlist_item.get(0);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(a.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Empty Field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this,web_view2.class);
                    launchWish.putExtra("k",a);
                    startActivity(launchWish);
                }
            }
        });
        //list 2
        L2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String b = wishlist_item.get(1);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(b.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Empty Field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this,web_view2.class);
                    launchWish.putExtra("k",b);
                    startActivity(launchWish);
                }
            }
        });
        //the end for 5 lists

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

I only want to retrieve 5 data from my firebase. You can see my firebase table here

[You can see my firebase table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLYmP.png)

I have been fixing this since yesterday and got no answers. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you try to log the `data` object inside "onDataChange()" method, is it something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: No sir @AlexMamo

Comment: Then is your onDataChange even triggered? Besides that, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: I print out the wishlist_item with textview and it give me all data from firebase database but when I try to get like this .get(1) and which got error @AlexMamo

Comment: Is this happening when you click on L1 or L2?

Comment: It crashed when I click L2 @AlexMamo

Comment: Are you clicking on the L2 before the data is completed loaded?

Comment: @AlexMamo I can't even click activity page crash when I add L2 button function. Is there any way to retrieve data without loop or another ways. I would really appreciate your help sir

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: Ok sir I really apricate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, you are getting the following error:

> "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size 1 at java.util.ArrrayList.get()"

Because you are trying to get an element from an "ArrayList" at a position that doesn't exist. As I see at the following reference:

```
Firebase-root -> Users -> "GRUK ... cL03" -> Wishlist
```

There are two items there, however, the error message is quite explicit saying that there is only one. Most likely, the Wishlist of the second user "T9az ... I4v2", which I think is the real logged-in user contains a single item in the Wishlist, and hence that error. So to solve this, always make sure you can find elements at the corresponding indexes before using them, instead of blindly assuming that an element is always present.

Comment: Ah yes you are right but when I add more button then data quantity in database the app got error. How can I handle this? There will be 5 button always but there will not be 5 items in database ever it will be empty or 1 or 2 or 3. So how can I handle this? @Alex Mamo

Comment: Very simple, check the size of the array before accessing one of its elements. For example, if you want to get an element from the second position (index 1), make sure the size of the array is `wishlist_item.size() >= 2`, right?

Comment: where can I put sir I cannot put it in L1 onClick @Alex Mamo

Comment: You need to put that condition every time you try to access an element from an array. You always need to make sure that the particular index exists.

Comment: Got it sir I really apricate your help. Would you mind telling me how can I only accept 5 items to firebase  DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                            .getReference().child("Users")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Wishlist");
                    myRef.push().setValue("http://www.librarything.com/isbn/" + passURL).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {}

Comment: I only want to restrict from program is there any way like >=5 or some way to restrict the input quantity to firebase?  @Alex Mamo

Comment: The simple solution is to check the size of the array when you write new data to Firebase.

Comment: Thanks sir. Thank you for telling me the way to do I really apricate your help <3 May you have a day filled with kind words, positive thoughts, happy people, and beautiful moments. @Alex Mamo